# Can't Receive MVC ViewBag(always null) property after $http post

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I am using MVC 5 with angularjs and SSRS 2008 R2 and just trying to display report posted data by angularjs form and display it in @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, new { Height = 600, Width = 1200, SizeToReportContent = true, frameBorder = "0", })

My MVC Controller is returning this 
**ViewBag.ReportViewer = reportViewer;
return View();** but my post angularjs function is not getting any ViewBag.REportViewer property on response data.
Please just let me know if I am making any mistake while posting, because always my ViewBag.ReportViewer is null.
Please see (html) for @html.ReportViewer at the bottom and (angularjs $http.post) postIncomingMaterialData for call.

Sorry I pasted most of the code here, but had no choice.
Thanks.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict'

  angular.module('GAiiNSApp').controller('GFIReportModalCtrl', ['$scope', 'getEmployeeNameFctry', 'getGrvNoFctry', '$http', '$log', '$rootScope', '$filter',
    function($scope, getEmployeeNameFctry, getGrvNoFctry, $http, $log, $rootScope, $filter) {



      $scope.getGRVNo = function(val) {
        return getGrvNoFctry.getGRVNoData('/Stores/StoresAPI/GetGRVNo', val).then(function(res) {
          var grvNo = [];
          angular.forEach(res.data, function(OBJ) {
            grvNo.push((OBJ));
          });


          return grvNo;


        });
      };

      $scope.getEmployee = function(val) {
        return getEmployeeNameFctry.getData('/Stores/StoresAPI/GetEmployee', val).then(function(res) {
          var users = [];
          angular.forEach(res.data, function(OBJ) {
            users.push((OBJ.NAME).trim());
          });


          return users;


        });
      };

      $scope.SubmitData = function() {


        $scope.myobject = {};
        $scope.myobject.StartDate = $scope.Date1;
        $scope.myobject.EndDate = $scope.Date2;
        .employeename = $scope.empName;
        $scope.myobject.grvno = $scope.grvNo;

        $http({
          method: "POST",
          url: '/Stores/Materials/IncomingMaterial',
          params: {
            StartDate: $scope.myobject.StartDate,
            EndDate: $scope.myobject.EndDate,
            HandedOverTo: $scope.myobject.employeename,
            GRVNo: $scope.myobject.grvno,
          },
          cache: false
        });





      }


    }
  ]);

})();

(function() {
  angular.module('GAiiNSApp').factory('postIncomingMaterialData', ['$http'], function($http) {

    $http({
      method: "POST",
      url: MYURL_URL,
      data: myObject,
      cache: false
    });

  });

})();

(function() {

  angular.module('GAiiNSApp').factory('getEmployeeNameFctry', ['$http', '$q',
    function($http, $q) {
      return {
        getData: function(url, val) {
          return $http({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            params: {
              nameSearch: val,
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  ]);
})();



(function() {
  'use strict'

  angular.module('GAiiNSApp').factory('getGrvNoFctry', ['$http', '$q',
    function($http, $q) {
      return {
        getGRVNoData: function(url, val) {
          return $http({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            params: {
              grv: val,
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  ]);
})();
```

```html
@using ReportViewerForMvc; @using System.Drawing @using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms; @using System.Web.UI.WebControls
<script src="~/Areas/Stores/Controllers/StoresNG/StoresCtrl.js"></script>
<div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="padding: 10px; min-height: 500px;  margin-left: 10px;" ng-controller="GFIReportModalCtrl">
  <fieldset>
    <h3>Report</h3>
    <hr />
    <form name="MeForm" class="form-inline" novalidate>
      <div class=" form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <label class="col-xs-5 col-sm-2 col-md-4" for="date1">Start Date:<span style="color:red">*</span>
        </label>
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" id="date1" name="fdate" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{$root.format}}" ng-model="$root.Date1" is-open="$root.popup1.opened" datepicker-options="$root.dateOptions1" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="$root.altInputFormats"
          uib-tooltip="Date must be in dd-mm-yyyy format" tooltip-placement="top-right" tooltip-trigger="'mouseenter'" tooltip-enable="!inputModel" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span>
          <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="MeForm.fdate.$invalid && MeForm.fdate.$touched">Start date is required</p>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class=" form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <label class="col-xs-5 col-sm-2 col-md-4" for="date2">End Date:<span style="color:red">*</span>
        </label>
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" id="date2" name="ldate" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{$root.format}}" ng-model="$root.Date2" is-open="$root.popup2.opened" datepicker-options="$root.dateOptions2" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="$root.altInputFormats"
          uib-tooltip="Date must be in dd-mm-yyyy format" tooltip-placement="top-right" tooltip-trigger="'mouseenter'" tooltip-enable="!inputModel" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span>
          <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="MeForm.ldate.$invalid && MeForm.ldate.$touched">End date is required</p>
        </p>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <label class="col-xs-5 col-sm-2 col-md-4" for="HandOver">Handed Over To:</label>
        <input type="text" id="HandOver" ng-model="empName" uib-typeahead="name for name in getEmployee($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingName" typeahead-no-results="noResults" typeahead-editable="false" typeahead-min-length="3" typeahead-wait-ms="500" class="form-control">
        <i ng-show="loadingName" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
        <div ng-show="noResults">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found...
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <label class="col-xs-5 col-sm-2 col-md-4" for="GRVNo">GRV No:</label>
        <input type="text" id="GRVNo" ng-model="grvNo" uib-typeahead="grvno for grvno in getGRVNo($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingGRVNo" typeahead-no-results="noResults" typeahead-editable="false" typeahead-min-length="3" typeahead-wait-ms="500" class="form-control">
        <i ng-show="loadingGRVNo" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
        <div ng-show="noResults">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found...
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="row">

        <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <br />
          <br />
          <div class="form-group  col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 pull-right">


            <button type="submit" class="btn submitbtn" ng-click="SubmitData()">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">

      </div>
      <div class="row">

      </div>

      <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="border: red;">

        <div>


          <div>

          </div>

          @{ if (ViewBag.ReportViewer != null) { @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, new { Height = 600, Width = 1200, SizeToReportContent = true, frameBorder = "0", }) } else {
          <p>Message -- The ViewBag is still null</p>
          } }
        </div>



      </div>
    </form>

  </fieldset>



</div>
```

Comment: Are you setting the Viewbag item in `IncomingMaterial` action method ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing, .......... ViewBag.ReportViewer = reportViewer; return View() . <br> if you want I can paste my controller here.

Comment: Finally I got it, it was the security issue with SSRS.

Comment: But just to conclude my issue, when I am getting the ViewBag.ReportViewer to the angularjs controller/$scope and logging it, it is showing the entire mvc view returned from controller not just the ReportViewer. How can I get only reportviewer content to my $scope and replace that in my html view/part.